# Find words starting with letter entered by user in specified file - bash

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk

I want to create bash script, which will find all words starting with user entered letter in specified file (specified in script or create user input for it too).
I am a little bit more than total beginner in linux, my code is:

```
    #! /bin/bash

echo 'Please enter starting letter of Name'
read name
result=$(awk '/$name/ {print}' /home/beka/scripts/names.txt)
echo "$(result)"
```

this results error like:

```
    Please enter starting letter of Name
G
/home/beka/scripts/test.sh: line 6: result: command not found
```

what I am doing wrong? I tried to search awk examples but can't find exact solution.
Thank you in advance.

---

EDITED CODE

```
#! /bin/bash

echo 'Please enter starting letter of Name'
read name

if [[ $name == [A-Z] ]]
then 
awk "/$name/{print}" /home/beka/scripts/names.txt
else
echo '0'
fi
```

EDIT
names.txt is a list of names

```
Michael
Christopher
Jessica
Matthew
Ashley
Jennifer
Joshua
```

ANOTHER EDIT

```
#! /bin/bash

echo 'Please enter starting letter (Uppercase) of name'
read name

if [[ $name == [A-Z] ]]
then 
echo "---Names starting with $name---"
awk "/$name/{print}" /home/beka/scripts/names.txt
elif [[ $name == [a-z] ]]
then
awk "/$name/{print}" /home/beka/scripts/names.txt
else
echo '---------'
echo 'Names not found'
fi
```

Comment: `echo "$(result)"` should be `echo "$result"`. And $name is not known to awk when you put it in single quotes.

Comment: You need to use double quotes instead of single quotes in order to properly expand variables

Comment: How do you define *word*? is it sequence of alnums and underscore, sequences of non-whitespace? How are they stored in `names.txt`?

Comment: @user1700494 in this case i would use `awk -v` option and not double quotes... especially when depending on user input.

Comment: @pLumo, `-v` has problems of its own with backslash. Better to use an environment variable and `awk`'s `ENVIRON` array.

Comment: I added changed code, thanks to "pLumo" double quotes does work, I forgot about it when it goes to variables :)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas this file is just list of names.

Comment: is it possible that user returned to "Enter first letter of name" after "not found" instead of ending?

Comment: @BekaShvelidze Depending on how your file is organized (please provide example input), this may find occurences of the entered letter at other positions on the line, too ... And yes, you can use a loop that only terminates after the user has entered a valid letter.

Comment: it's just list of names
```
Michael
Christopher
Jessica
Matthew
Ashley
Jennifer
Joshua
Amanda
Daniel
David
James
Robert
John
```

Comment: I added another update to code, now if I search Uppercase letter it gives names starting with, if search for lowercase letter searches names containing it, but if I search Uppercase letter which isn't starting letter for any of names it gives "Names starting with e.g. G and shows nothing bellow it instead of saying "Names not found".

Comment: is there any way to search any case ( upper or lower) and to match it with starting letter anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo "$(result)"` is trying to execute a command named `result` courtesy of the `$(result)` part, hence the error message `result: command not found`.

Try this (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

result=''
while [[ -z "$result" ]]; do
    echo 'Please enter starting letter of Name'
    read name

    if [[ $name == [A-Z] ]]
    then 
        result=$(awk -v name="$name" 'index($0,name)==1' /home/beka/scripts/names.txt)
    else
        echo '0'
    fi
done
echo "$result"
```

To make the search case-insensitive:

```
awk -v name="$name" 'index(tolower($0),tolower(name))==1' /home/beka/scripts/names.txt
```

Obviously you'll also have to change `$name == [A-Z]` to `$name == [a-zA-Z]` or `$name == [[:alpha:]]` if you want to be able to accept a lower case letter as the search character.

Comment: it lacks "done" instead of "fi"before last echo, but it works fine as loop.

Comment: it is case sensitive as I see, is there any way to search e.g. James with j ( I mean to search with lowercase and find Uppercase as starting letter)?

Comment: it makes no difference.

Comment: I fixed the missing `done`. I had already added the code to make it not case-sensitive at the bottom of my answer. What makes no difference?

Comment: now it's clear to me, changing code piece and adding a-z to search criteria made the magic :) Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. Give it some time to see if you get a better answer and then see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Comment: can we add "Nothing found" when it can't find match and returns to user input?
now it doesn't utilize text after "else", only returns to user input.

Comment: [Chamelon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are discouraged in this forum, please always just accept an answer to the question you asked and ask a new followup question if you have one.